# Citrix MDX Toolkit and Android ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, citrix

I have an corporate app that I usually wrap for SecureHub distribution using the MDX Toolkit. Recently I changed one of my layouts to use a ConstraintLayout instead of another RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView. The layout hierarchy is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Linearlayout>
        ...some stuff..
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView>
    <Spinner>
    <ScrollView>
        <ConstraintLayout>
            .... more Stuff
        </ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The app is successfully wrapped without error, but when you start the app under Securehub, everything below the Spinner is not rendered, and I don't get why. I'm using the MDX Toolkit Version 18.12.0.

```
Vendor:     Citrix Systems
Version:    18.12.0.e02de0de09e5110d57969152867fb5300f7b3682.77786
Built Date: 03-12-2018 03:15:31
```

Some more details about the app:

```
ext {
    supportToolsVersion = '27.1.1'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myappId"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionName "myappName"
        versionCode 3064
    }
    ...
}
```

Has anybody got any experience with this ?

Comment: Dear @dave did you get this fixed? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Sadly not, I have reverted everything back to RelativeLayouts. But we have a newer version of the MDX toolkit now, so I will test that again soon (tm).